# How do I use the same shortcut to switch panes and windows in Tmux?

Tags: shell, tmux

How do I get the same shortcut to switch panes AND switch windows in tmux?

If I'm in the rightmost pane in the current window and I hit "Control-b + Right", tmux should realize that I'm in the rightmost pane and move me over to the next window.

Is this possible in tmux?